# Windows 7 "Resets" when shutting down

Tags: windows-7, shutdown

Whenever I shut down my Windows 7 box, I see what I can only describe as a "reset." To me, it appears that various programs exhibit the same symptoms as if they were *immediately, un-gracefully terminated,* and they lose lots of data that was in memory (although was it only in memory?).

I typically keep my machine without rebooting for over a week.

Examples of symptoms include:

- Winamp playlist reverts to empty
- Chrome history is gone
- Event viewer shows services terminating with errors (eg. Windows Search service)

I'm shutting down via the normal Start > Shutdown or Start > Reset workflows, nothing exceptional.

What's going on?

Comment: The first thing that comes to mind is [Faronics DeepFreeze](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deep_Freeze_(software))

Comment: Do you have any cleaning software that might rise to the occasion when you shut down?

Comment: I'd check the `WaitToKillServiceTimeout` , `AutoEndTasks` , `HungAppTimeout`, and `WaitToKillAppTimeout` registry keys.

Comment: @Wutnaut I don't run any software, and I don't think any are running on my system.

Comment: @ssnobody check them for what? What values should I expect?

Comment: For numbers that differ from default values, since this behavior is unexpected on clean/default installs of windows. Technet lists their default values. As an example, here is one such page for [WaitToKillServiceTimeout](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc976045.aspx)